# JDK Documentation Examples Licence

Tags: license, java, documentation

What is the license for code examples in the JDK's documentation?

For example: [The code examples present in this javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html).

Additionally, in general do code examples embedded in documentation always fall under the main license for a project unless explicitly stated otherwise?

Comment: At the bottom of the page you are linking it says "*All rights reserved. Use is subject to [license terms](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/java_se-12-final-spec/license.html) and the documentation redistribution policy.*" Have you looked at these license terms already? What is your specific question regarding these terms?

Comment: Ahhhh I don't know how I missed that. Those terms make a lot more sense. It's still not clear to me whether these terms permit the re-use/derivation of a given code example.

Comment: Check this section: "2. License for the Distribution of Compliant Implementations. ..." I think this is pretty restrictive. And you don't have the right to sub-license, so taking the code and using it and then licensing for example under Apache or MIT as part of your own package is not possible.

Comment: I guess the only other question would then be at what point does a given example stop being considered "trivial" and start being covered under copyright? Those examples from the link in the question look like just about the simplest/most minimal way to implement what is being demonstrated but of course it's java so everything is verbose/complicated. Would they qualify as "trivial"? Also is there a good rule/standard for evaluating triviality?

Comment: I am not in the position to judge if code can be considered 'trivial'. But there have been [questions and discussions here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/search?q=trivial) which you might want to read.